# ¿Como ignoro el archivo storage de git?

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-commit, gitignore

Cuando subo este archivo a mi servidor online me sobreescribe el que me sirve en el server y no logro ignorarlo de git.

El archivo .gitignore que tengo esta asi:

```
/vendor
.env

/public/storage
public/storage
/public_html/storage
public_html/storage
```

Sin embargo no me ignora el archivo.

[image: gitignore storage fail.png]

Puedo notar que **VS Code** coloca de color gris el texto de la carpeta **/vendor** y del archivo **.env**, cuyo cuales si son ignorados.

La verdad no se que estoy haciendo mal. De antemanos gracias al que pueda ayudarme.

Comment: `.gitignore` evitará que se agreguen archivos sin seguimiento al conjunto de archivos rastreados por git, sin embargo, git continuará rastreando cualquier archivo que ya esté siendo rastreado. Es ese el caso?

Comment: @porloscerros si, creo que es mí caso.

Comment: Para dejar de rastrear un archivo, debes eliminarlo del índice. Prueba con este comando `git rm --cached public/storage` (o `public_html/storage`, no entendí bien cuál es) y el archivo se eliminará del indice en el siguiente commit.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ bro eso lo solucionó, mil gracias, colocalo como respuesta para darte la puntuacion.

Comment: Genial. Encontré otra pregunta con respuesta, que es prácticamente lo mismo que ésta, por eso el comentario anterior. Si te parece bien vota por esa para evitar duplicados. Saludos.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ genial genial, votaré por duplicado.